# Packet Sniffing using Raw Sockets in Linux in C

Tags: linux, network-programming, network-protocols, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I need to write a packet sniffer in Linux that detects HTTPS packet that are sent and save the url from the request. I found code for this in [security-freak](http://www.security-freak.net/raw-sockets/raw-sockets.html) and ran it. This code runs and only sniffs the received packet but I need to get the sent packet in the sniffer.
How do I get the sent packet in this code?

I can't use any library like libcap (forbidden).
The code is :[sniffer.c](http://sjb.ir/sniffer.c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using ETH_P_ALL instead of ETH_P_IP as the protocol.  ETH_P_IP only listens for incoming IP packets.

Comment: If the goal is to see http packets, why not use ETH_P_IP?  You don't need everything.

Comment: The goal is to see outgoing http packets.  ETH_IP_P only sees incoming packets.  See thread:  http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/9604.1/0603.html

Comment: Where is the official documentation for these kind of macros? I have been searching all over the POSIX standard but I can't find nothing. Also Linux kernel doesn't say anything!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use any library? Homework?

It's hard to answer without having examples from your code, for example how you set `sll_pkttype`.

The [urlsnarf](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=backtrack-3-man/urlsnarf) tool in the [dnsiff](http://www.monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) suite could be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

With appropriate [libpcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/) or [DNET](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/dnet.3.txt) usage You should be able to get all network 
traffic on the desired layer (protocol - 5) (also this outgoing).
But You should know that already.

You need to go through the above libraries manuals and find the appropriate filtering.

Comment: we cant use any library like libcap  or dnet

Comment: Are you sure that your system allows detecting outgoing packets?  You could use libpcap to determine if it's even possible.

Comment: @bua "I can't use any library like libcap (forbidden)."